# Pandas COUNTIF equivalent (preserve duplicate values, see description)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, function, count

I have the following pandas column1 and I want to create a column2 displaying the count of the value in each row in the column1.

I do not want to use pandas value_counts as I do not want to group by the values of the column.
Column1 :

```
COL 1   
VALUE1  
VALUE2
VALUE1
VALUE1
VALUE1
VALUE3
VALUE2
VALUE1
VALUE3
VALUE2
```

Desired result :

```
COL 1   Desired Result
VALUE1  5
VALUE2  3
VALUE1  5
VALUE1  5
VALUE1  5
VALUE3  1
VALUE2  3
VALUE1  5
VALUE3  1
VALUE2  3
```

Comment: "do not want to use pandas value_counts as I do not want to group by the values of the column" Out of interest why would you require this?

Comment: I want to match the values of the column 1 with the values of the column2. With value counts I would get, value1 : 5, value2 :3, value3: 1. This is not the desired result (format wise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value_counts` does not require you to group and it creates a `series`
which you can `map` back to your `df`:

```
df['Resired Result'] = df['COL 1'].map(df['COL 1'].value_counts())
```

prints

```
     COL 1  Resired Result
0   VALUE1               5
1   VALUE2               3
2   VALUE1               5
3   VALUE1               5
4   VALUE1               5
5   VALUE3               1
6   VALUE2               3
7   VALUE1               5
8   VALUE3               1
9   VALUE2               3
```

Comment: Έτοιμος! Δεν με άφηνε το πρώτο λεπτό!

Answer (score 2):

[`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) might be more efficient, but you can also achieve it with [`groupby.transform('count')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Resired Result'] = df.groupby('COL 1')['COL 1'].transform('size')
```

Output:

```
     COL 1  Resired Result
0   VALUE1               5
1   VALUE2               3
2   VALUE1               5
3   VALUE1               5
4   VALUE1               5
5   VALUE3               1
6   VALUE2               3
7   VALUE1               5
8   VALUE3               1
9   VALUE2               3
```